# Analyze the programs/commands frequency since boot up (command vs. PID histogram)

Tags: kernel, process, logs, monitoring

I would like to see which program got a PID most frequently and second frequently in my system since the last reboot. If I run `top` now, I can see the `PID` column and the `COMMAND` column but only for system state at current moment. I'd like to dig up from some log or enable some log so whenever somethings gets a new `PID` with some `COMMAND`, I would like to add a row to a table, and analyze that table. For example:

```
      1 root      20   0  168424  10960   7820 S   0.0   0.1   0:02.78 systemd
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 kthreadd
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-events_highpri
      9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:02.26 ksoftirqd/0
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:31.57 rcu_sched
```

You can see that a few `PID`s already exited (like 5, 7, 8). I'd like to record them all once they started. Is there a command or utility that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a native solution using `auditd` which uses the audit features built into the Linux kernel.

```
auditctl -a always,task # the one below should also work; pick one
auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S clone,fork,vfork,execve
systemctl restart auditd
# wait a while and use your computer
```

Alternatively, write `audit`'s config file, enable the service and reboot

```
echo "-a always,task" > /etc/audit/rules.d/logpid.rules
echo "-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S clone,fork,vfork,execve" > /etc/audit/rules.d/logpid.rules
systemctl enable auditd
systemctl start auditd
reboot
```

Then, after reboot, use for a while and check audit report:

```
aureport --start today --interpret --executable --summary # sort by execs the number of audit events
aureport --start today --interpret --syscall --summary
```